# How to setup Fresh Planet Ane Google Play Game Services Correctly?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-cs6, flashdevelop, ane

Hey everyone so I've been at this for days now. I am setting up the Google Play Game Services ANE from Fresh Planet  using Flash CS6 and Flash Develop with the latest Adobe AIR 17.0. I have the ANE connected to the library path in Flash CS6 also have it added to the library in Flash Develop.

This is how I have everything setup in my startScreen Class:

[image]

Now once I click the button on my Android Device the Application Crashes immediately after doing so here is how my XML is setup:

[image]

I followed all the instructions as posted in the forums of Fresh Planet . So i don't understand why it's crashing and not displaying anything. Please any help would be appreciated or if you know of any other free methods of using google play game services and wouldnt mind helping me out I would really appreciate it thank you!   [Fresh Planet ANE](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Google-Play-Game-Services)